# Loading Clojure.core.match

Tags: exception, clojure, load, match

I'm new to Clojure and I'm wanting to use Clojure core.match:
https://github.com/clojure/core.match

I've setup my project with TextMate using the following bundle: https://github.com/swannodette/textmate-clojure

My project.clj is as follows:

```
(defproject Prototype "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Prototype ARS Implementation"
  :dependencies [[clojure "1.3.0"] [org.clojure/core.match "0.2.0-alpha6"]])
```

In terminal, I executed:

```
cake deps
```

Which downloaded the correct version of Clojure and the Clojure.core.match jar files.
Now I'm editing my 'src/Prototype/core.clj' and I'm wanting to use the match functionality.

I've tried using both the provided code on the GitHub page:

```
;; when using HEAD
(use '[clojure.core.match :only [match]])

;; when using the latest released alpha
(use '[clojure.core.match.core :only [match]])
```

This is my current code:

```
(ns Prototype.core
  (use '[clojure.core.match.core :only [match]]))

(println
  (let [x [1 2]]
    (match [x]
      [[1 2]] "It worked!"
      :else "It failed!")))
```

When I load the file into the cake repl; I get the following error:

```
lib names inside prefix lists must not contain periods
```

Any ideas?
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(ns Prototype.core
  (:use [clojure.core.match.core :only [match]]))

(println
  (let [x [1 2]]
    (match [x]
      [[1 2]] "It worked!"
      :else "It failed!")))
```

There's no need to quote in the `ns` form.

(I've assumed `clojure.core.match.core` was the correct namespace. If it doesn't work use `clojure.core.match` instead.)